# Junit test function which returns a string

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

I have a function inside a class :

```
public String covertToLowerCase(String sliceName) {
        sliceName = sliceName.trim().toLowerCase();
        sliceName = sliceName.replaceAll("\\.txt$|\\.dat$", "");
        return sliceName;
    }
```

I want to test this using Junit. I have created a separate test file which has the following:

```
  public class MyControllerTest {

  private MyController myController;
  private static final String SLICE_NAME = "Hello World";

  @Test
  public void shouldReturnSanitizedString() throws Exception {
  String expected = myController.covertToLowerCase(SLICE_NAME);
  // assert that actual and expected are same
  }
```

I am not able to understand how to test this and all the other examples are specific to their functions. I just want the function to return a sanitized string? How can I go about this?

Comment: What does it mean "sanitized", your regular expression seems like simply delete txt or dat extension from the string. Anyway, You should have smth like `String expected = "hello world";` for your test and then  `String actual = myController.covertToLowerCase(SLICE_NAME);` and then `assetEquals(expected, actual)`. Then you want to test it the same way on other different inputs like: "test.txt", "test.dat", "test.doc", "", ...

Comment: I don't understand. Why do you assign the return value to a variable called `expected`? That should be `actual`. `expected` is what you're actually expecting it to return.

Comment: Where is the field *myController* initialized in the test? If the function/method is *static*, it can be used and tested without initialization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to test, first you have to prepare data to test, the input value, the expected value => call test function with input value => get the actual value return by function under test => assert the expected value with the actual value. Here is a [list of assert function](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html) that you can use.

```
public class MyControllerTest {

  private MyController myController;
  private final String SLICE_NAME = "Hello World";
  private final String expected = "hello world";

  @Test
  public void shouldReturnSanitizedString() throws Exception {
  String actual = myController.covertToLowerCase(SLICE_NAME);
  // assert that actual and expected are same
  assertEquals(expected, actual);
  }
}
```

Comment: If I want to test some other function :  public String createSqlFromSchema(List<MapSchema> mapSchemas) {
        String template = "%s %s";
        List<String> colList = mapSchemas.stream().map(m -> String.format(template, m.getColName(), m.getDataType()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return String.join("\n", colList);
    } .  What do I have to provide as a parameter in the test function? When I log the current parameter, it shows a reference and not the actual value.

Comment: @TeeJay When you have a new question, ask a new question. Dont get into "more questions in comments" ping pong. Besides: do you think *anybody* wants to read source code written up in comments?

Comment: @TeeJay please take noted @GhostCat's comment.
Most importance thing is you need to learn about [junit](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/) before working with it.
For your question, you need to test for function `createSqlFromSchema(List<MapSchema> mapSchemas)` the input of this function must be a `List<MapSchema>`, let's initialize your list and pass to the test function. More things, you want to get value of a list, then go through one by one to get the value.

Answer (score 2):

For the record, more "real world" tests would rather look like:

```
public class MyControllerTest {
  private MyController underTest = new MyController();

  @Test(expected=NullPointerException.class)
  public void testConvertToLowerCaseWithNull() {
    underTest.convertToLowerCase(null);
  }
```

The above is just an example - your method could decide for example to throw an IllegalArgumentException instead. And you want to make sure that your production code *does* actually throw an exception for invalid cases.

```
  @Test
  public void testConvertToLowerCaseWithEmptyInput() {
    assertThat(underTest.convertToLowerCase(""), is(""));
  }
```

I recommend using `assertThat()`, together with [hamcrest](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/) matchers - as the resulting code is simply easier to read and understand.

And then you continue adding more testcases. You step back, and you think upfront about the things to test here. You want to make sure that "e" stays "e", that "E" turns into "e" ... and so on.

Other things here:

- especially when doing such input/output-only testing --- do **not** use fields/constants in your test method. You want that your tests are **self contained** as much as possible. In order to understand my test - you just need to look into the method body. Your approach requires you to lookup what those constants actually contain!
- be precise: there is absolutely no need to have *throws Exception* on your test method. It doesn't throw - so the signature shouldn't announce that!
- **bad** naming in your production code. Your method doesn't *only* turn into lower case. It also replaces content. The method name should express that. As of now, that method name is **misleading**. That is the worst thing your code can do: mislead the reader into believing what code does, but doing more/something else instead!